# Macro quicker in Microsoft VBA than in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone explain me, why my macro is way quicker to execute in Microsoft Visual Basic (> 10 secondes ) than in an excel sheet with a button (< 10 min ...)

Bellow is the code of the macro. Thanks.

```
Sub RecoverData()    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim BI As Workbook
Dim supplier As Range
Dim filter As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

'## Open both workbooks first:
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set BI = Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\data.xlsx")


With BI.Sheets("Panel") ' reference source sheet
Set supplier = .Rows(2).Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("B1").Value, lookat:=xlWhole) ' try searching wanted header in BI
Set filter = .Rows(2).Find(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("B2").Value, lookat:=xlWhole) ' try searching wanter header in BI
lastRow = .Range(Col_Letter(Range(supplier.Address).Column) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' find the last row with data in column A


If Not supplier Is Nothing Then ' if found
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=Range(filter.Address).Column, Criteria1:=Array("P01*", "P02*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues ' find the column to filter on
    Range("E3:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1") ' find the column to get value from
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    MsgBox "Column Name Not Found"
End If
End With
BI.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A5").Font.Color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Comment: Which type of button have you used? There are several Range objects in your code which refer to the active sheet because they are not prepended with a period to make them refer to the sheet in the With statement. Is that on purpose?

Comment: So i used a form control button.
And no you are right, that was not on purpose, but it does not change the execution time

Comment: You need to an accurate timer and measure each block of code to  tie it down.  Try this https://rotchvba.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/a-high-resolution-timer-in-vba/

Comment: You may think it has no effect what button type was used, but for instance clicks on ActiveX buttons are triggered in a completely different way than form buttons. As s Meaden says: best to time your code to find out which part is causing the slowdown.